# Double integral of $1/f(x;y)$ diverges in proximity of the curve $f(x;y)=0$.

Tags: integration, polynomials, improper-integrals

In one dimension, one can consider improper integrals of the form
$$\int_a^b \frac{1}{f(x)} \mathrm d x$$
where $f$ is a polynomial with a zero at $x=a$, and $f>0$ on $(a;b]$. That integral will be always divergent, because of the singularity at $x=a$.

Now, I was wondering if this continues to be true in two dimensions.

> Let $f(x,y)$ be a polynomial in two variables, and let $\Omega \subset \Bbb R^2$ be a bounded connected open set. Suppose that $\gamma=\{ (x;y) \in \Omega : f(x;y)=0 \}$ is a curve which cuts $\Omega$ into two nonempty regions
>   $$\Omega^+ = \{ (x;y) \in \Omega : f(x;y)>0 \} \quad \mbox{ and } \quad \Omega^- = \{ (x;y) \in \Omega : f(x;y)<0 \}$$
>   The integral $$I= \int_{\Omega^+} \frac{1}{f(x;y)} \mathrm d x \mathrm d y$$
>   is improper, since the integrand function is unbounded in proximity of $\gamma$.
>
> Does the integral $I$ ever converge, or is it always divergent?

I tried with some examples, like $f(x;y)=1-x-y$ and $f(x;y)=1-x^2-y^2$ inside the rectangle $(0;1)^2$. I also tried $f(x;y)=1-xy$ inside the rectangle $(0;2)^2$, and always got divergent integrals.

Comment: Why does the one dimensional integral converge? For instance, consider $a=0, b=1, f(x) = x^2$. We know that $1/x^2$ is not integrable near $0$.

Comment: @YuxinWang You are right! I made confusion with the other kind of improper integral. I will edit my question, since as it is now it does not make sense

Comment: Hint: the integral is of course fine away from the zeros of $f(x,y)$. For the region near the zeros, consider changing to the polar coordinate $(r,\theta)$ where $r$ is the distance from the zero and $\theta$ goes between $0$ and $2\pi$.